# Add a variable to a variable

Tags: php

Sorry for a misleading title, was hard to explain the problem so short...

So I've got a few variables named `$exp_lvl1`, `$exp_lvl2` and so on...

To make it more simple I got `$exp_lvl` (which just gives an error because it don't exist and that's normal in this case) and I got the number needed in a variable `$next_exp`.

How do I put these together? I have tried `$exp_lvl.$next_exp` and it didn't work. How should I do?

Comment: Firstly, rephrase your question and make it understandable for a person who knows nothing about your problem. Secondly, take a look at [arrays](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php).

Comment: What does "it didn't work" mean?

Comment: @PeeHaa I've got the error undefined variable $exp_lvl.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want something like this:

```
$x = ${$exp_lvl.$next_exp};
```

**Test:**

```
<?php

$exp_lvl = 'var_';
$next_exp = '1';
$var_1 = 'okay';

$x = ${$exp_lvl.$next_exp};
echo $x;

?>
```

See @ [PHPFiddle](http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/b97-p65)

Comment: Hm, the script took all from 1 to 10 and wrote on the page. I want it to wrote from only one.

Comment: @JoakimMelin yes, it was my first post, I edit that but didn't removed the old part, thought maybe helps ...

Comment: @JoakimMelin I removed the first part which wasn't relevant to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$exp_lvl."".$next_exp
```